# Hashing of a Bitstring to Sort by Similarities

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hash, similarity

**Problem description:**

We have a lot of bitstrings of the same size. The number and the size of bitstrings is huge. E.g.: 10100101 and 00001111.

Now there is a distance function that just counts the number of same bit positions. In this example: distance is 2 - because the third last and last bits are set by both bitstrings.

-> Now we can make a tour through the bitstrings with the maximal distance, because every bitstring can be converted to a vertex which is connected to all other bitstrings (by the distance function).

**Goal**

However, this has the complexity of O(N²). My idea is to use a hashing function, that preserves the similarities and than do a simple sort on the hash values. This should result in a near maximum tour. Of course it is not the best result, but it should be a somewhat good result.

**Current Problem**

My own hashing function rates the left bits higher than the left bits. So that they have a more significant effect to the sort.

**Actual Question**

- Does such an algorithm exists?
- Is it possible to use Locality-Sensitive Hashing (LSH) for that aim and if so, can you formulate the respective algorithm. (I didn't understood the algorithm right now)

**Thank you, guys!**

Comment: popcount(A&B) + Stanford bithacks

Comment: Can you explain your comment a little bit further?

Comment: Coeesponding `1` bits between A and B -> bitwise AND between A and B. popcount() := function to count the number of `1` bits. https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html

Comment: The distance of to bitstrings is not the problem. I want to sort them by a hash function, that preserves similarity.